# Trouble Setting A Maximum Length For A Text Field

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, boolean

I'm having trouble setting a maximum length for the content of a text field. The process I took was implementing the UITextFieldDelegate in my header file. I then defined (and then called) this method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
return (newLength > 5) ? NO : YES;
}
```

This was a method that I got by suggestion here on the site. I've also tried this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
NSUInteger newLength = [zipCode.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
return (newLength > 5) ? NO : YES;
}
```

"zipCode" is the the outlet that I connected to the text field. Each time I've changed the code I've made sure to reconnect the outlet. I have a feeling it's a very simple thing that I'm missing. Apologies if this is a little convoluted, I have a lot to learn! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    return (zipCode.text.length + string.length <= 5);
}
```

Then, in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    zipCode.delegate = self;
    //.....
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Hmm, still not working. Should I be connecting it somehow in the Interface Builder that I don't know? Or maybe there's a problem with the Interface Builder displaying this? This is the third method I've tried and they all make sense when I analyze them but then they don't work...

Comment: Put `zipCode.delegate = self;` in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller.  It might not be connecting with the IB but you can do it manually with the line above.

Comment: Happy to help @MxmastaMills! Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the outlined checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Happy to help.  Glas u got it fixed @MxmastaMills!

Comment: It didn't work when i tried setting its delegate in viewDidLoad, it worked when I set the delegate where the alertbox's UITextField was created.