# Set max length of UITextField in a UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

I want to set a max length to my `UITexField` but this is inserted in a `UIAlertView`,
I'm trying to find out the right information to solve this problem,on this beautiful site but there is nothing.

Could someone help me to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670018/trouble-setting-a-maximum-length-for-a-text-field

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a better implementation of the UITextFieldDelegate method, as it will not remove the text end in front of the users eyes, it just prevents the user from typing in more text.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if (newString.length > MAXLENGTH)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, and set your controller as the delegate of the text field (see Anoop Vaidya answer)

Answer (score 0):

As you can access the alertView's textField by

```
UITextField *theTitleTextField = [alertView valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
```

If you want to find your's textfield added, then use `textFieldAtIndex:` as suggested by *Martin R*.

Then implement `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([textField.text length] > MAXLENGTH) {
        textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH-1];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I assume the OP meant the (optional) *text input field* of UIAlertView. You can access that with the `textFieldAtIndex:` method.

Comment: my 20 minutes wasted  to find default one. This question was so straight forward or this is the magic of EDITs?

Comment: No, the edit fixed only typos. (I just noticed that you have removed "I am not interested in iOS" from your profile page :-)

Comment: @MartinR: I read the question as soon as it was posted, and edits within 5 minutes are not shown, i guess. And yes iOS, I dont want job for that profile, I love osx :) I always upvote on osx problems :D

Comment: @MartinR:  And recently(few days back) I changed that to "I am ZERO in iOS"

Comment: @user2202681: Did you set the delegate, e.g. `theTextField.delegate = self;` ?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: You can remove that, you have 500 upvotes on iOS.

Comment: @MartinR: But I haven't created a full-fledged app. Only buttons, labels, textfields etc. I think you only notified me ios 32 bit so %d and mac 64 so %ld.